# I want to copy the output of unix and sqlplus into a file

Tags: sql, oracle, unix, plsql, sqlplus

I am using Solaris.  I have to log into sql plus and run some queries, which give a huge result set.

I want to copy all that into a file.  Is there any command for it in unix or sqlplus ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use the `SPOOL` command:

```
SQL> SPOOL /opt/output

SQL> SELECT ...

SQL> SPOOL OFF
```

Answer (score 1):

setup Oracle environment

(there are ways around specifying username/password on the command line - not the best way especially when other users can 'ps' on the server and see your password)

```
sqlplus -s username/password <<-!!
set trimspool on trimout on pages 0 feedback off linesize 1000 echo off verify off
spool file.out
select sysdate from dual;
exit
!!
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are on the command line then just use the > and 2> to redirect stdout and stderr respectively to log files

`func > out.log`